# how to change given date and time automatically with datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a small project where every Friday of everyweek at 6:00 PM EST a new special reward is given and reset for a game.

Example:
Every Friday at 6:00 PM EST the special offer resets and comes out with a new one. What I want to do is let's say its Tuesday and I want to know how many Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds are left until Friday 6:00 EST.

The code I have right now works but the issue is I have to manually update the date for the next friday.

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
reset = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 18, 18, 00, 00)
print(reset-today)
```

After the 18th I would have to manually enter next fridays date, how could I do that automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant way but this should help..

```
import datetime

#import relativedelta module, this will also take into account leap years for example..
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

#Create a friday object..starting from todays date
friday = datetime.datetime.now()

#Friday is day 4 in timedelta monday is 0 and sunday is 6.  If friday is 
#today it will stop at today..

#If it is friday already and past 18:00, add 7 days until the next friday. 
if friday.hour > 18:
    next_week = datetime.timedelta(7)
    friday = friday - next_week
#else iterate though the days until you hit the first Friday.
else:
    while friday.weekday() != 4:
        friday += datetime.timedelta(1)

#the date will now be the first Friday it comes to, so replace the time.
friday = friday.replace(hour=18, minute=00, second=00)

#create a date for today at this time
date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>>2018-03-17 04:54:34.974214

# calculate using relativedelta
days_til_next_fri = relativedelta(friday, date_now)

print("The Time until next friday 18:00 is {} days {} hours {} minutes and {} seconds".format(days_til_next_fri.days, days_til_next_fri.hours, days_til_next_fri.minutes, days_til_next_fri.seconds))

>>>The Time until next friday 18:00 is 6 days 13 hours 50 minutes and 15 seconds
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for the help and the comments in the code.

Comment: Hi, I added an if statemet because it is still friday but now it has to reach the next friday. I also had to change around the last calculation.. let me know it works ok :)

Comment: It works great! Do you know how I would go about formatting it to say like 2 Days 13 hours and 20 minutes?

Comment: I have updated my answer.. note the extra import of `relativedelta` at the top and the `calculate` and `print` at the bottom